# Bootstrap slideshow previous and next buttons/ arrows not showing in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and having hard time figuring out why the previous and next arrows are NOT show in the middle of the slideshow images.

The arrows are showing on the top of the slideshow and can barely seen.

Here is what I used to add the slideshow to the page.

```
 <div id="mainBanner" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="imgs/image1.jpg" class="slidImageSize"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="imgs/image2.jpg"  class="slidImageSize"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="imgs/image3.jpg" class="slidImageSize"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="imgs/image4.jpg" class="slidImageSize"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#mainBanner" data-slide="prev">&lt;</a> 
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#mainBanner" data-slide="next">&gt;</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below) -->
<script src="resources/css/js/bootstrap.js"></script></div>
```

I can add some styling to a custom CSS class but I am wondering if I missed anything when using bootstrap.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Have you added bootstrap css ?

Comment: @Ariel yes I have added bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/), instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;` you have to put `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/6SVCM/